# I'm not getting the else output

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

While I was testing a few things I tried this idea, but I can't get it to work:

```
parx = input("Write your parX: ")
pary = input("Write your parY: ")

while pary != 0 and parx != 0:
    cociente = int(parx) / int(pary)
    print ("Su cociente es: ",cociente) 
    parx = input("Write your parX: ")
        pary = input("Write your parY: ")
else:
    print("your ordered pair is not divisible")
```

I expect the output of the else, but it only shows an error when i write `0,0` on my variables, I want that when I enter `0 0` the program says "your ordered pair is not divisible"

The error says:

```
  File "Ejercicio2PDF3.py", line 6, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: Please format your question..

Comment: `input()` is taken in as a string, and `'0'` is not `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` returns a string, and `0 != "0"`

Either parse your strings immediately

```
parx = int(input("Write your parX: ")) 
pary = int(input("Write your parY: "))
```

Or check against strings

```
while pary != "0" and parx != "0":
```

Note too that you should be using some error checking. If the user enters a non-number, your program will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Just one mod needed.
Change:

```
while pary != 0 and parx != 0:
```

To:

```
while int(pary) != 0 and int(parx) != 0:
```

Final Code:

```
parx = input("Write your parX: ")
pary = input("Write your parY: ")

while int(pary) != 0 and int(parx) != 0:
    cociente = int(parx) / int(pary)
    print ("Su cociente es: ",cociente) 
    parx = input("Write your parX: ")
    pary = input("Write your parY: ")
else:
    print("your ordered pair is not divisible")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert `string`s into `int`:

```
parx = int(input("Write your parX: "))
pary = int(input("Write your parY: "))
```